# Bar graph with GraphView

Tags: android, android-graphview

I know I must be missing something obvious, but I can't see how to display a bar graph rather than a line graph.
I've set up the data using `GraphViewSeries`. The data all looks correct, but I don't see an option on `GraphViewStyle` to change the style from a line graph to a bar graph.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using `LineGraphView` as your class for displaying the data? Use `BarGraphView` for a bar graph.

Comment: Oh lordy. That was obvious. Thanks!